# displaying div depending upon image class within slide gallery/carousel

Tags: jquery

I have a slide gallery which adds a class `curSlide` to an image when it is being displayed within the gallery.

I have divs containing text corresponding to the slides within the gallery, ie. `#group2-text` should be displayed when a `.group2-img` has the class `curSlide`. Both gallery-text divs are set as `display: none` within the css. Is it possible to get jquery to display the correct div depending upon the `curSlide` class?

html:

```
<div class="page-content" id="projects-commercial-content">
  <div class="gallery" id="projects-commercial-gallery">
    <div class="gallery-holder">
      <div id="projects-commercial-slides" class="slides"> 
        <img id="comm1" src="images/commercial1.jpg" class="slide-image group1-img" alt=""/>
        <img id="comm2" src="images/commercial2.jpg" class="slide-image group1-img" alt=""/>
        <img id="comm3" src="images/commercial3.jpg" class="slide-image group1-img" alt=""/>
        <img id="comm4" src="images/commercial4.jpg" class="slide-image group2-img" alt=""/>
        <img id="comm5" src="images/commercial5.jpg" class="slide-image group2-img" alt=""/>
        <img id="comm6" src="images/commercial6.jpg" class="slide-image group2-img" alt=""/>
      </div> 
    </div><!--gallery-holder-->
    <div class="gallery-text" id="group1-text">
      <h3>project <span class="abbrev">group 1</span></h3>
      <p>Group 1 description text. Suspendisse ultricies molestie nisi id bibendum. Mauris bibendum ipsum at massa malesuada eu venenatis velit pretium.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-text" id="group2-text">
      <h3>project <span class="abbrev">group 2</span></h3>
      <p>Group 2 description text etc. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse imperdiet justo ac ligula congue posuere. Aliquam erat volutpat </p>
    </div><!--gallery-text-->
  </div><!--gallery-->
</div><!--page-content-->
```

The part of the gallery js adding the class is here:

```
    _fade: function (navigateData) {

            // put hidden to slide above current
            this.slides.eq( navigateData.to ).addClass('curSlide').css({
                zIndex: 10
            // fade in next
            }).fadeIn(this.options.fade.interval, this.options.fade.easing, $.proxy(function(){

                    // hide previous
                    navigateData.currentSlide.removeClass('curSlide').css({
                        display: "none",
                        zIndex: 0
                    });                             

                    // reset zindex
                    this.slides.eq( navigateData.to ).css({
                        zIndex: 0
                    });                 

                    this.current = navigateData.to;

                    this._trigger("navigateEnd", ( this.current + 1 ), this);

            }, this));
    },
```

I didn't write the gallery js and I'm not really sure how to adapt it to display the corresponding div/text.

Any help is much appreciated! Please let me know if more details are required. TIA!

Comment: it's a modified version of [slides.js](http://slidesjs.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but give it a try. Modify the part of the gallery script

```
_fade: function (navigateData) {

        //hide text and show new text
        $('.gallery-text').css('display','none');
        var curImgClass = $(this.slides.eq( navigateData.to )).attr('rel');
        $('#' + curImgClass + '-text').css('display','block');

        // put hidden to slide above current
        this.slides.eq( navigateData.to ).addClass('curSlide').css({
            zIndex: 10
        // fade in next
        }).fadeIn(this.options.fade.interval, this.options.fade.easing, $.proxy(function(){

                // hide previous
                navigateData.currentSlide.removeClass('curSlide').css({
                    display: "none",
                    zIndex: 0
                });                             

                // reset zindex
                this.slides.eq( navigateData.to ).css({
                    zIndex: 0
                });                 

                this.current = navigateData.to;

                this._trigger("navigateEnd", ( this.current + 1 ), this);

        }, this));
},
```

Comment: Thanks, but the gallery now doesn't play - it stays at slide 1.

Comment: I just made a small change to it.

Comment: Perfect! I kept the rel attribute suggested by Alex C, and this combined with your alterations works. Many thanks! :-)

Comment: Add the `rel` attributes in your html that @AlexC showed above to the `img` tags, and then try it.

Comment: Yeah, I was working off of the html in his answer, and not your original post... sorry about that!
You're welcome =)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this idea, unfortunately cannot test:

HTML code modified:

```
<div class="page-content" id="projects-commercial-content">
  <div class="gallery" id="projects-commercial-gallery">
    <div class="gallery-holder">
      <div id="projects-commercial-slides" class="slides"> 
        <img id="comm1" src="images/commercial1.jpg" class="slide-image" alt="" rel="group1"/>
        <img id="comm2" src="images/commercial2.jpg" class="slide-image group1-img" rel="group1" alt=""/>
        <img id="comm3" src="images/commercial3.jpg" class="slide-image group1-img" rel="group1" alt=""/>
        <img id="comm4" src="images/commercial4.jpg" class="slide-image" rel="group2" alt=""/>
        <img id="comm5" src="images/commercial5.jpg" class="slide-image" rel="group2"alt=""/>
        <img id="comm6" src="images/commercial6.jpg" class="slide-image" rel="group2" alt=""/>
      </div> 
    </div><!--gallery-holder-->
    <div class="gallery-text" id="group1">
      <h3>project <span class="abbrev">group 1</span></h3>
      <p>Group 1 description text. Suspendisse ultricies molestie nisi id bibendum. Mauris bibendum ipsum at massa malesuada eu venenatis velit pretium.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-text" id="group2">
      <h3>project <span class="abbrev">group 2</span></h3>
      <p>Group 2 description text etc. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse imperdiet justo ac ligula congue posuere. Aliquam erat volutpat </p>
    </div><!--gallery-text-->
  </div><!--gallery-->
</div><!--page-content-->
```

**JS piece of code**:

```
  _fade: function (navigateData) {

            // put hidden to slide above current
            $(".gallery-text").hide();
            this.slides.eq( navigateData.to ).addClass('curSlide').css({
                zIndex: 10
            // fade in next
            }).fadeIn(this.options.fade.interval, this.options.fade.easing, $.proxy(function(){

                    // hide previous

                    var detElement =  this.getAttribute('rel');

                    $(".gallery-text[rel="+detElement+"]").fadeIn();


                    navigateData.currentSlide.removeClass('curSlide').css({
                        display: "none",
                        zIndex: 0
                    });                             

                    // reset zindex
                    this.slides.eq( navigateData.to ).css({
                        zIndex: 0
                    });                 

                    this.current = navigateData.to;

                    this._trigger("navigateEnd", ( this.current + 1 ), this);

            }, this));
```

Comment: This also caused the slideshow to stall at slide 1. I'm happy to to have two separate js files to do this, if it's easier. Although I suspect not...